# Spring Boot 2: Refresh properties on the fly not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I have followed this official tutorial [Getting Started Centralized Configuration](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) using spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and spring cloud Finchley.M8

But refreshing properties on the fly (Without restart) is not working.
After Some debugging, I noticed that in method refresh() from ContextRefresher.class, it returns the changed keys correctly, but after reconstructing the bean annotated with @RefreshScope in the next use. It still sees the old value not the updated one.

> Note: This was working perfectly with spring boot v 1.5.6 and spring cloud Edgware.RELEASE.

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: there is a bug in boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: yes, I see.
Will postpone the upgrade until things are stable.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

It seems spring.cloud.config.uri in spring boot 2.0.1.RELEASE always looking for port 8888 and not accepting other values, so I put the below configuration (you can ignore it, as it is the default value for the client, and **the server should run on port 8888**)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

I also tried to expose all other services in the client for testing as follows

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

or use the following to allow only refresh

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: refresh
```

Then called POST method not GET for refreshing

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:8080/actuator/refresh -d {} -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Finally, it works.

Comment: My problem was on version 2.0.0.RELEASE, maybe they fixed it in 2.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: I faced the same issue on the latest version, but I fixed it as above

Comment: I have tried now by running the config server on port 8888 with spring boot V 2.0.0.RELEASE and the problem is the same.
I think they managed to make a fix some how in the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Instead of Method "POST" , use "OPTIONS" method to call the "actuator/refresh" for spring boot 2.0 or higher.

For lower versions (<2.0), use the endpoint "context/refresh"

Make sure , you have `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` defined in `application.properties.`

Answer (score 1):

Use below in application.properties-

```
management.endpoint.refresh.enabled=true
management.endpoint.restart.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.info.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,refresh
```

Using yaml configuration file it was not working for me and when switched to  properties file, it worked with above configuration.

Thanks

Comment: Even I tried the same and surprisingly it worked for me. Surely its a bug