# Spring Boot 2.4.x - @RefreshScope is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I already went through many links like [@RefreshScope and /refresh not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311068/refreshscope-and-refresh-not-working) and [Spring Boot 2: Refresh properties on the fly not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363043/spring-boot-2-refresh-properties-on-the-fly-not-working), but still things are not working for me.

I've developed spring-cloud-config-server

when I hit

> POST ==> http://localhost:8002/actuator/refresh

I get the response

> [
> "config.client.version"
> ]

It looks like its somehow not loading the changed properties

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

PropertyAccessBean.java:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="property-file")
public class PropertyAccessBean {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

PropertyAccessValue.java:

```java
public class PropertyAccessValue {

    private String name;
    private String description;


    public PropertyAccessValue(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PropertyAccessValue{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

UserController.java:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@RefreshScope
@Slf4j
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        log.info("Inside saveUser of UserController");
        return userService.saveUser(user);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseTemplateVO getUserWithDepartment(@PathVariable("id") Long userId) {
        log.info("Inside getUserWithDepartment of UserController");
//      return userService.getUserWithDepartment(userId);
        
//      return userService.getUserWithDepartmentWithFeign(userId);
        
        return userService.getUserWithDepartmentWithFeignAndResilient4J(userId);
    }
    
    
    @Autowired
    PropertyAccessBean propertyAccessBean;

    @GetMapping("/readkey")
    public PropertyAccessValue accesPropertyFile(){

        return new PropertyAccessValue(propertyAccessBean.getName(),
                propertyAccessBean.getDescription());
    }
}
```

bootstrap.properties:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://localhost:9296
```

application.yml:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8002

spring:
  application:
    name: user-service 

resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      department:
        register-health-indicator: true
        ring-buffer-size-in-closed-state: 5
        ring-buffer-size-in-half-open-state: 3
        wait-duration-in-open-state: 10s
        failure-rate-threshold: 50
        record-exceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
        - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        - java.io.IOException
        

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: refresh
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Comment: Why is `bootstrap.properties` in YAML format?

Comment: Whats the correct way? People often use the bootstrap.yml file

Comment: I would say that if a file _contains_ YAML, it should be called `*.yml`. When I try to parse `bootstrap.properties` (which is, despite its name, a YAML file) as a properties file, I get 5 properties, three of them empty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After 10 hours of crazy debugging I had to replace yml to properties file and its started working.

I'm not sure why yml was unable to pick up the changes, surely its a bug!.

application.properties

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:9296

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true

server.port=8002

spring.application.name=user-service

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.department.register-health-indicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.department.ring-buffer-size-in-closed-state=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.department.ring-buffer-size-in-half-open-state=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.department.wait-duration-in-open-state=10s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.department.failure-rate-threshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.department.record-exceptions=org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
```

Here is the response

```
[
    "property-file.name",
    "config.client.version",
    "property-file.description"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake lies in your `bootstrap.properties` file to really be YAML instead of a properties file. Please refer to the [documentation for properties file format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-). Your file is equivalent to the following:

```
spring=
cloud=
config=
enabled=true
uri=http://localhost:9296
```

So this file does *not* set `sping.cloud.config.enabled` to `true`, but instead some property called `enabled`, which is probably unused.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, where after making a POST request to the actuator refresh endpoint, I was getting:

```
[ "config.client.version" ]
```

This shows it noticed the changed but unable to fetch the changed data.

I got the refresh endpoint working, after adding `spring.cloud.config.name` in the bootstrap file of the service that was reading the data from the config server.

See below my bootstrap.yml for my product-service API.

```
spring:
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://localhost:8080/
  cloud:
    config:
      name: product-service
```